# how to use plaintext password as login with oauth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin

i am going to develop a .net application with oauth mechanism which is going to use existing database table for user infomations ( this database is shared by few other applications) My question is this user_login table have plain password currently.Can i use this plain password with oauth.

Note: As table is shared by other applications i can't encrypt the existing password now itself, planned to do this task later.

I have developed application by following below link,while registering new user details stored in database. in this password is stored as encrypted value but i need this stored in plain password format

https://github.com/MikeWasson/LocalAccountsApp

**Update:**

if i use inside of this method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials to use own table for login.it's secure or not? refer this [link](http://saifikram.com/2014/06/token-based-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-with-owin)

Answer (score 0):

Oauth implies token-based authorization, right? Each time u authorize by plain password u get token for permission another actions, so, you can store users passwords in plain text - but it's really low-secure desicion.

Comment: which oauth method to use plain text password, register and login?

Comment: worked example on msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Pay attention to `token` part

Comment: we need to store without encrypted password in database (like plain text password) if it's possible?

Comment: @SureshSankar you can change PasswordHasher property of your UserManager: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151662(v=vs.108).aspx#P:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.PasswordHasher

Comment: can i use my custom table for login process(without use of ASPNetUser table) oauth?

Comment: of course, as additional data inside your AuthorizeContext

Comment: if i use inside of this method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials to use own table for login.it's secure or not? refer below link 

http://saifikram.com/2014/06/token-based-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-with-owin